# Beautiful Soup can't access all images in a webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download all images of a product in [Trendyol](https://www.trendyol.com/aqua-di-polo-1987/unisex-kol-saati-apl12c195h02-p-3929108). The Soup does not see the div "gallery-container" when I try to use the find_all method. It's getting empty. After that, I tried to find all images on the page. I can't access all images. I get low-resolution images. However, when I check from chrome inspect, I can see the images with high-resolution. How can I get images?

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oGo5.jpg)

Code - GetProductInfo.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from os.path  import basename
import requests

class GetProductInfo:
    global session
    global html_text

def __init__(self,link):
    session = HTMLSession()
    html_text = session.get(link)
    html_text.html.render()
    self.soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.html.html, 'lxml')

def saveImages(self):
    for link in self.soup.select("img[src^=http]"):
        lnk = link["src"]
        with open("images/"+basename(lnk),"wb") as f:
            f.write(requests.get(lnk).content)
```

Code - test.py

```
from GetProductInfo import *
product = GetProductInfo("https://www.trendyol.com/aqua-di-polo-1987/unisex-kol-saati-apl12c195h02-p-3929108")
product.saveImages()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply regex out the JavaScript object hosting the image links, then parse with json. No need to render the page at all. The links are for the high resolution images viewable in that gallery.

```
import requests, json, re

r = requests.get('https://www.trendyol.com/aqua-di-polo-1987/unisex-kol-saati-apl12c195h02-p-3929108')
data = json.loads(re.search(r'PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__=(.*?);', r.text).group(1))
images = ['https://www.trendyol.com' + img for img in data['product']['images']]
print(images)
```